# MWS api Throtlling - Maximum request quota

Tags: amazon-mws

I don't understand something about mws throtlling.
For example with this api:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html

The Max request quota is 20. So I understand that I can submit 20 different ids on each request. But in the table there written that 'Maximum: Five Id values'.
So what the 20 represents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20 represents the maximum about of requests you can make at a time.  Each request can have a maximum of 5 Id values in the IdList.  So, essentially you can submit requests for 100 (20 * 5) product Id's at a time.  Then you have to wait until the quota is restored, which is 5 per second.  You are also capped by an hourly request quota, in this case 18,000 requests per hour.

Do some math to figure out how many requests you need to make and space those out so enough time is given for the restore to kick in.

Answer (score 2):

There are typically 2 or 3 components to Amazon throttling.

They use a modified leaky bucket algorithm.  The Quota is how many separate requests you can submit at a given instant, assuming you have not already consumed any requests.  This is how much the bucket can hold.

For every request you submit, the bucket 'leaks' one unit.

The restore rate, is how quickly the bucket refills.

For the API call you linked, how many requests can hypothetically be sent in 1 second?  If my math is right (give or take 1) you should be capable of making 25 requests in that first second, because you exhaust the bucket, but in the first second, it also refills 5 requests.

Keep in mind that Amazon caps you on many API calls with an Hourly / Daily cap.

***Edit***

Keep in mind the throttling caps how many ***Requests*** you can make, not how many ID's, reports etc etc can be submitted inside of each request.