# Amazon MWS - Request Throttled

Tags: amazon-mws

After reading the Throttling documentation https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Throttling.html and https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html , I've started honoring the `quotaRemaining` and the `quotaResetsAt` response headers so that I dont go beyond the quote limit. However, whenever I fire a few requests within quick succession, i get the following exception.

The documentation doesnt mention anything about any burst limits. It talks about maximum request quota, but i dont know how that applies to my case. I'm invoking the ListMatchingProducts api

```
Caused by: com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsException: Request is throttled
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsAQCall.invoke(MwsAQCall.java:312)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection.call(MwsConnection.java:422)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out.
`ListMatchingProducts` mentions that the Maximum Request Quota is 20. Practically this means that you can fire at max 20 requests in quick succession, but after that you must wait until the Restore Rate "replenishes" your request "credits" (i.e in my case 1 request every 5 seconds).

This Restore rate will (every 5 seconds) start to then re-fill the quota, up to a max of 20 requests. The following code worked for me...

```
class Client {
  private final int maxRequestQuota = 19
  private Semaphore maximumRequestQuotaSemaphore = new Semaphore(maxRequestQuota)
  private volatile boolean done = false

  Client() {
    new EveryFiveSecondRefiller().start()
  }

  ListMatchingProductsResponse fetch(String searchString) {
    maximumRequestQuotaSemaphore.acquire()
    // .....
  }

  class EveryFiveSecondRefiller extends Thread {
    @Override
    void run() {
      while (!done()) {
        int availablePermits = maximumRequestQuotaSemaphore.availablePermits()
        if (availablePermits == maxRequestQuota) {
          log.debug("Max permits reached. Waiting for 5 seconds")
          sleep(5000)
          continue
        }
        log.debug("Releasing a single permit. Current available permits are $availablePermits")
        maximumRequestQuotaSemaphore.release()
        sleep(5000)
      }
    }

    boolean done() {
      done
    }
  }

  void close() {
    done = true
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you might have seen this thread which explains it as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35491672/3047